# $L^{1}(\mathbb R) \cap L^{2}(\mathbb R) \cap C_{0}(\mathbb R)\subset H_{1}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

Put, $C_{0} (\mathbb R)=\{f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C: f \text { is continuous on} \ \mathbb R \  \text  {and } \lim_{|x|\to \pm \infty}f(x)=0 \}$(= Continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ vanishing at $\infty$)  and  $A:= L^{1}(\mathbb R) \cap L^{2}(\mathbb R) \cap C_{0}(\mathbb R).$

> My Question: Given $|f|\in A$. Can we always expect $|f|\in H_{1}(\mathbb R)=\{ f\in \mathcal{S'}(\mathbb R): (1+|\xi|^{2})^{1/2}\hat{f}\in L^{2}(\mathbb R) \}$ ([Sobolev spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space)), Or, we we can  produce a counter example ?

Thanks,

Comment: $H^1$ functions are almost everywhere differentiable, so any nowhere differentiable continuous function with compact support is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A simple family of counter examples come from the Sobolev embeddings. Since
$$
W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R})\hookrightarrow C^{0,\frac{1}{2}}(\mathbb{R}),
$$
your identity would imply that continuous functions are always Hölder continuous.